# How can I write this simple function in mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, mathematical-foundations

```
POINTS_TABLE = [3, 5, 7, 1]

function score(answer) {
  result = 0
  for i in 0..4
    result += POINTS_TABLE[answer[i]]
  return result
}

answer = [1, 2, 1, 0]

s = score(answer)
```

The sum performed is 5 + 7 + 5 + 3 = 20. It uses the values from the input as the indexes to read from the POINTS_TABLE.

This is the style of the answer I'm trying to work out:
\begin{equation}
score(answer) = \sum_{i=1}POINTS\_TABLE_{answer_i}
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't really understand. What's wrong with the expression you already have? "Mathematical notation" isn't a programming langauge with defined syntax and semantics; it's much more like a natural language and there are multiple ways of writing things. Some may be more or less appropriate, depending on what you want to use the notation for.

Comment: Oh, I thought math notation was strict. The expression I have was my best attempt, I assumed it was wrong.

Comment: So do mathematicians reading the notation it have to interpret it and try to guess what's meant?

Comment: No, the author of the paper should explain all non-standard notation.

Comment: However did you get the idea that this was a functional program? O.o

Comment: I thought it might be more about the Mathematics, but your notation is o.k. readable without any explanations.

Answer (score 2):

While you are free to use whatever notation you want, as long as you explain it, it seems that the simplest solution here would be

> $$ score(answer) = \sum_{i=0}^3 POINTS\_TABLE[answer[i]] $$

This should be self-explanatory in most circumstances.

Comment: What makes this the simplest? I've never seen notation that uses an array index like that. Would a non-programmer understand it?

Comment: It's something I bet a lot of readers will understand. It's definitely not *the* simplest. It's just one reasonable solutions, there are many others.